# Using label values in Google Stackdriver alerting documentation

Tags: notifications, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have setup alerts on speicific contents in the logs. 
e.g. I get an alert when the log message contains something like this

```
"message":"DB already exists.","code":"USER_ALREADY_EXISTS"}
```

I have added labels https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels so that I can extract the appropriate message body ("DB already exists") and the code ("USER_ALREADY_EXISTS")
I have named these as `message` and `code` respectively.

In the altering policies, in the `Documentation (optional)` section I want to provide the value of these labels
Following https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables, I tried writing something like

```
${metric.label.code}
${resource.label.message}
```

However, when I get my alerts on slack, they are rendered as `null` values.
Is there a way to get this information from the logs?

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue, even though I've followed the instructions regarding grouping on the metric label. The documentation says "If your alerting policy uses grouping by labels, any labels not used in grouping are not present in the result."  So, I've grouped on the metric label.  Nonetheless, the lable value is still null in the documentation section.  I've tried not grouping at all, and grouping with different aggregation functions. None of them work. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `${metric.label.code}` and `${metric.label.message}` is correct, but it requires that these metric labels are preserved. If you have an [Aggregation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#aggregation) that includes a `crossSeriesReducer` but which does not include `metric.label.code` and `metric.label.message` in the `groupByFields`, then this substitution will no longer work (since the aggregation could produce more than one value for each variable).